# text shadow not working in w3.org site

Tags: css, cross-browser, w3c

My question is why w3.org use this type of properties which is not cross browser compatible
**text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF** this is Not working in IE7!

Comment: Anybody can check-------left navigation heading STANDARDS used class name= ribbon  with text shadow.

Comment: The real question is – why shouldn’t they?

Comment: you are mad Konrad Rudolph I am asking that why w3.org use this property if this is not working

Comment: gourav-Khanna - It does work, just not in an ancient browser like IE7. Thirtydot answers why.

Answer (score 2):

It's down to [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

> Progressive enhancement uses web
>   technologies in a layered fashion that
>   allows everyone to access the **basic
>   content and functionality of a web
>   page, using any browser** or Internet
>   connection, while also providing those
>   with better bandwidth, **more advanced
>   browser software** or more experience **an
>   enhanced version of the page.**

IE7 is an ancient browser that does not support `text-shadow` (and the `filter` version is horrible).

[Sites do not need to look the same in every browser.](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)